# Execute an AJAX method against a secure URL with a non-trusted certificate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ssl, https

I have a site which makes AJAX JSONP calls to a secured (SSL) web server. If I use a unsecured (HTTP) web server , everything works fine, but when I change to the SSL version, the call never returns. I've checking with fiddler and the error is following:

The remote server (192.168.150.85) presented a certificate that did not validate, due to RemoteCertificateChainErrors.

This means that some intermediate certificate is missing, but I don't know which one. In any case I need to deal with the situation where some installations has invalid certificate credentials.

It is known, that if you try to execute an AJAX method against a secure URL with a non-trusted or expired certificate the browser will warn your user about that, regardless of how or what you're trying to do. In browser you can accept the risks, even in C# you can implement a callback to accept these risks as well. But I don't know how to do it in Javascript/JQuery.

Do someone have an idea about how to handle this situation?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you go to the SSL site with a browser?

Comment: I mean you should definitely have this server's certificate issues straightened out. Is that possible for you? If you have access to the server its literally just an issue of placing the certs in the right apache directories.

Comment: Hi! If I go with a browser, it don't work as well because the problem is that the jquery.ajax() method is waiting for a confirmation. If I use fiddler, after the error message the request works, but under the browser, no error message is shown and jquery.ajax waits for confirmation ... until the end of the days :)

Comment: @thatnotidiotguy: You're right, but I'm not using apache, but self hosting with c# (httplistener). The certificates are in the right places on the server, but as they are not official, they cannot be verified and the browser/ajax/fiddler will always show this error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is not possible/recommended. It is indeed not a good idea. We work now with real certificates which is quite cheap (there are even free ones) and easier to manage in our test environment, where we have several mobile devices, types of clients and so on.